# Cannot read property 'length' of null (javascript)

Tags: javascript, null

While trying to debug I am get the 'length' null error with this line.    It is written just like the book instructed, so I don't understand why it is giving me the error?
Thanks, =)

```
if (capital.length < 1) {
```

***( here is the full code as requested.. SORRY)***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var capital = window.prompt("What is the capital of Missouri?","")

if (capital.length < 1) {
    document.getElementById("firstdiv").innerHTML="Sorry you don't feel like playing.<br /> The Capital of Missouri is Jefferson City.";
}
else {
    if (!window.confirm("Is that your final answer?")){ return true;

        document.getElementById("firstdiv").innerHTML = "The capital of Missouri is: <bold>" + capital + "</bold>, so says you.";
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: post full code please

Comment: What language is this? JavaScript?

Comment: Because you never set `capital`.

Comment: The variable capital is null.

Comment: Done =)  sorry about that

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The proper test is:

```
if (capital != null && capital.length < 1) {
```

This ensures that `capital` is *always* non null, when you perform the length check.

Also, as the comments suggest, `capital` is `null` because you never initialize it.

Comment: I am so sorry.. Yes it is in JavaScript

Comment: I would probably write this as `if (capital && capital.length < 1)` now and not explicitly reference `null`.

Answer (score 4):

This also works - evaluate, if capital is defined. If not, this means, that capital is undefined or null (or other value, that evaluates to false in js)

```
if (capital && capital.length < 1) {do your stuff}
```

Comment: If `capital` is non-null but points to the empty string, will the logic be correct with this solution?

Comment: probably not, in 2021 is better use nullish coalesce operator ??
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Answer (score 1):

From the code that you have provided, not knowing the language that you are programming in. The variable `capital` is null. When you are trying to read the property length, the system cant as it is trying to deference a null variable. You need to define `capital`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (capital.touched && capital != undefined && capital.length < 1 ) { 
//capital does exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
if(capital !== null){ 
//Capital has something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Try cache

try{

//Your Code

}
catch(err){

console.log(err)

}

Comment: Could you expand your answer to help OP a little as to why this answer may work for them?