# i18next version 1.7.2 cannot read property 'status' of null error

Tags: i18next

I had a difficulty in using i18next to get i18n'ed versions of strings.
I am having cannot read property 'status' of null error on line 1381 of i18next-1.7.2.js

my json files are located in locales/translation-en.json,... etc.

My init code is like below:

```
i18n.init({ lng:"en" , resGetPath: "locales/__ns__-__lng__.json",  ns:"translation"},
function(t) {
text.nodeValue = i18n.t("app.name");
....
});
```

[Cannot read property 'length' of null (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731559/cannot-read-property-length-of-null-javascript) didn't apply for my case.

Comment: Related issue in github: https://github.com/jamuhl/i18next/issues/214

Comment: When I changed i18next-1.7.2.js code to circumvent error.status issue and used jquery library my issue is resolved. I will post detailed explanation as an answer as soon as time limit expires (the doesn't allow me to post answers to my own question for 8 hours or so)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I inspected the source code of i18next-1.7.2 line:1382
It seems that there is a missing null check in the code. 
error is null and error.status is being checked.
So I added a simple null check.

Here is the change in the code:

Old code (from original i18next-1.7.2.js) :

```
                    if (error.status == 200) {
                        // file loaded but invalid json, stop waste time !
                        f.log('There is a typo in: ' + url);
                    } else if (error.status == 404) {
                        f.log('Does not exist: ' + url);
                    } else {
                        f.log(error.status + ' when loading ' + url);
                    }
                    done(error, {});
```

proposed code:

```
                if (error == null){
                    done(error, {});
                }else{
                    if (error.status == 200) {
                        // file loaded but invalid json, stop waste time !
                        f.log('There is a typo in: ' + url);
                    } else if (error.status == 404) {
                        f.log('Does not exist: ' + url);
                    } else {
                        f.log(error.status + ' when loading ' + url);
                    }
                    done(error, {});
                }
```

When I changed the code like above, it didn't work.
When I included jquery.js file it worked.
Developer of i18next Jamuhl knows about the subject.