# Null value error in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am counting how much inventories i have by location name. Everything works, but if `location name = null` i get errors in my console `Cannot read property 'name' of null`

```
$scope.stored = function(name) {
        $scope.count = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventories.length; i++){
            if($scope.inventories[i].location.name == name){
                $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
            } 
        }
            return $scope.count;
        };
```

Comment: change `if($scope.inventories[i].location.name == name){` to `if($scope.inventories[i].location && $scope.inventories[i].location.name == name){`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot read property 'length' of null (javascript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731559/cannot-read-property-length-of-null-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pulling the answer out of the comments and posting here for future visitors:

You need to change `if($scope.inventories[i].location.name == name){` to `if($scope.inventories[i].location && $scope.inventories[i].location.name == name){`